# HTML/CSS creating responsive menu

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why I can't access toggleMenu to style/turn off/etc.

HTML:

```
<header>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="/">ONE</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">TWO</a></li>
    <li><a href="/">THREE</a></li>
</ul>
<a href="/" id="toggleMenu">&#9776; MENU</a>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
#toggleMenu {
  color:aqua;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Wasted over 30 minutes on this one and it should be a no-brainer.  Hoping someone can see what I cannot.

Comment: Styling should just work provided you have the css included. turnoff - you will have code for it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/f2sjtdyd/ Cannot reproduce

Comment: Wish I could add more info.  It recognizes the rest of my CSS, not sure why it won't recognize this id

Comment: Do you have multiple element with same id `toggleMenu` ?

Comment: Silly question, but are you sure CSS is being loaded with the HTML?

Comment: Everything else works great.  I decided to start with this great RWD example, http://blog.g-design.net/post/42617934013/create-an-accessible-toggle-menu-for-mobile#notes, and work it into my code backwards.

Comment: Maybe there's another style somewhere that's overriding this one.  You could check that by right-clicking the element and choosing Inspect Element.  Depending on your browser there'll be a section somewhere in the developer tools that shows what CSS styles are currently applied to the element and where they came from.